# How to format current date and save into date object

Tags: java, parsing, date

I want to get the current date and format it and save it into a date object. I try the following code but get an error saying that the date is unparseable. Here is what I have tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
Date date = f.parse(new Date().toString());
```

I need the actual date to remain as a date object as that will be needed for some other code later on

Comment: `new Date()` already represents the current date. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: At least try printing `new Date().toString()` in order to see the current output format and get an idea why the code may be failing. Also, your code example has no sense at all (building a new `Date` from an actually new `Date`).

Comment: A `Date` has no format: it's just a moment in time, with it's own internal representation. You can *represent* a `Date` by a `String` with a certain format.

Answer (score 2):

When using a format that you defined, you need to pass a `String` value to the `parse` method that follows the pattern and `new Date().toString()` definitely doesn't follow the `dd/MM/yyyy` pattern.

Also, `new Date()` is already a `Date` object, you don't need to transform it to a `String` and back to a `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`Date` class' Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) the default `toString()` method always return the format

> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

which is not the one you define in the parser.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the actual date to remain as a date object

Seems like you only want the Date part and not the Time part of the `new Date()` object. Knowing this, you have two paths to follow:

1. Using plain Java. You will need a Calendar object:

   ```
   public Date getCurrentDate() {
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
       c.set(Calendar.MINUTES, 0);
       c.set(Calendar.SECONDS, 0);
       c.set(Calendar.MILLISECONDS, 0);
       return c.getTime();
   }
   ```
2. Using an external library that handles date and time easily like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

   ```
   public Date getCurrentDate() {
       return new LocalDate().toDate();
   }
   ```